# .NET MVC Core 2.2 - Can't access user related entity (foreign key)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am writting my first own app in MVC Core 2 and I am having trouble accessing Estate Entity which have foreign key to User. I have check my db, Estate record is storing userId correctly:

[image]

When I try to get `context.Estates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);` I get an Estate entity, but with `User == null`:

[image]

When I try to access it via :

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var estate = user.Estates.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

I get null exception on Estates list. Also trying to save it this way gives me an exception:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
user.Estates.Add(estate);
```

However when I type it like that, it saves data correctly in db:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
estate.User = user;
context.Add(estate);
```

I have no clue what I did wrong here. I provide my code below, I hope you can give me some tips/advices.

Thats how i build context based on IdentityDbContext:

```
public class ReaContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public DbSet<Estate> Estates { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=rea-dev;User Id=postgres;Password=admin;");
    }

    public ReaContext(DbContextOptions<ReaContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public ReaContext()
        : base()
    { }
}
```

My User model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public List<Estate> Estates { get; set; }
}
```

Estate model:

```
public class Estate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

And thats how I add services:

```
services.AddDbContext<ReaContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=rea-dev;User Id=postgres;Password=admin;"));

services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ReaContext>();
```

I also provide Fluent Api migrations:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Estates",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.SerialColumn),
            CreationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            UpdateDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            ExpirationDate = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: false),
            City = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 100, nullable: true),
            UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Estates", x => x.Id);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Estates_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                column: x => x.UserId,
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "AspNetUsers",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
            PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
            TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
            LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
            LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
            AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to get related data of a model.

1. **Eager loading**: means that the related data is loaded from the database as part of the initial query.
2. **Explicit loading**: means that the related data is explicitly loaded from the database at a later time.
3. **Lazy loading**: means that the related data is transparently loaded from the database when the navigation property is accessed.

So in your case you can use `Eager loading` by doing the following:

```
context.Estates.Include(e => e.User).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
```

---

For more information read this: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

---

Edit: an example for achieving `Eager loading pattern` on the `IdentityUser`:

You can achieve this by either:

1. Injecting `UserManager<User> _userManager`.
2. Creating your own `Service` as in `Service/Repository Design Pattern`.

Let's say you picked the first option. Then you can do the following:

```
var user = await _userManager.Users
                 .Include(u => u.Estates)
                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(YOUR_CONDITION);
```

Comment: Thank you, I found a [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) for lazy loading, I added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies ` package and changed my relations to virtual as docs says. Now it works just fine. Thank you very much, I was stuck on this couple hours since I didn't know about loading types.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to access `user.Estates` with eager loading? I found some examples but all of them on context object, there is no `include` method for user. It works with lazy loading.

Comment: I think yes you can. By injecting the `UserManager<User> _userManager` then you can use it in a similar way shown in the answer. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: I meant for single user object, like on `var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User); user.Estates.DoStuff();`, but it wont work without lazy loading. Isn't it that `_userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Estates)` is same as `context.Users.Include(u => u.Estates)`?